# Send email from magento

Tags: email, magento, sms, transactional

From our Magento 1.7.0 shop, we would like to send an email to a SMS gateway, when the shipping transactional email is sent. I really can't figure how to do this - any ideas?

The email to the SMS gateway should have the following content:

SMS gateway email adress: 432342343@smsgateway.com
Title: customes phonenumber
content: we have sent your ordre today

Best regards, 
Jesper

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to observe the `sales_order_status_history_model_save_before` event.  From within you observer:

```
public function observeStatusHistorySave($observer)
{
     $status = $observer->getObject();
     if (!$status->getIsCustomerNotified()) {
         return false;
     }

     $customer = $status->getOrder()->getCustomer();
     sendSms($customer->getTelephone(), "etc...");         
}
```